# How to auto populate column with Google spreadsheet formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm a noob at Google spreadsheets. I'm actually a PPC advertising specialist, and I'm looking to build some tools in Google Spreadsheets. The first tool that I built was a method to add a "+" symbol in front of a select group of words in a column. The formulae is the following:

```
=CONCAT("+",SUBSTITUTE(A2," "," +"))
```

So basically column A contains a words like:

"these are my keywords" (A2 in this example)

The formulae takes these words, and adds a "+" in front of each, so then column B would display:

"+these +are +my +keywords" (B2 in this example)

Now the problem I'm having is that I have to take B2, and drag it down to copy the formulae down. But if I was to add more keywords to column A, I would have to remember to keep on dragging the rest of the columns down (B column and possibly other columns that use similar formulas that depend on column A's keyword list).

How can I setup my formulae in B2:

```
=CONCAT("+",SUBSTITUTE(A2," "," +"))
```

.. so that it automatically takes all the keywords in column A, and auto populates the entire column B?

I've read that it can be done with ARRAYFORMULA? Please advise!

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

For Arrayformula to work, you just have to give the normal function a range instead of a cell, as such:

`=ARRAYFORMULA("+"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A;" ";" +"))`

Also, you can't have any values under it, but it will tell you.